# Adding linear distances along polyline segments (start/end stations) to attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, routing, linear-referencing, route, polyline-creation

This seems like a pretty simple application but I've been struggling to find the appropriate tool.

I have a polyline feature (a trail network) that contains fields with attributes about each segment of the trail (for example sideslope).

So a single trail may contain multiple segments if the properties of the trail change along the length.

[image: image showing trail network segments and attribute tables]

My goal is to add information like this to to my attribute table, as well as add stationing points to my map that cumulatively add distance across the entire trail, not just each segment.

[image: attribute table goal]

I've dug into this more using LRS and am attempting to calibrate routes. I've created endpoints for each segment with a distance measure using the "locate points along line" plugin. When I calibrate my LRS I'm only getting routes from a few of the trails.

[image: output of LRS calibration]

It seems like I'm missing some basic concept here about routes and linear referencing even after lots of searching and watching YouTube videos.

Comment: I guess it would help to add a screenshot with 1) What you have and B) what you want to achieve.

Comment: Especially this *"a single trail may contain multiple segments"* would be nice to see